# Want to make a min-max textbox like in the image

Tags: html, css

[image: AS Shown in the image]

As described in the image,

I would like to make the textbox like this.

I have tried it using min max but it is not working.

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" placeholder="Number"><br>

  </div>
```

How can i make it like in the image?

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: its working perfectly, whats wrong with this

Comment: i want to make a style like in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this i have added custom colors , you can replace it with icons

```js
$(function(){
 $('#up').on('click', function(){
  var value = $('#value').val();
  if(value == 5){
   return false;
  }
  value++;
  $('#value').val(value);
 }); 
 
 $('#down').on('click', function(ev){
  
  var value = $('#value').val();
  if(value == 0){
   return false;
  }
  value--;
  $('#value').val(value);
  
 }); 
});
```

```css
.relative {
 position:relative;
 width:280px;
}
input {
 width:100%;
 display:inline-block;
 border:2px solid #E5E4E4;
 appearance:none;
 padding:5px 0 5px 5px;
}
#up {
 width:25px;
 height:17px;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 background:#096;
 border:none;
}
#down {
 width:25px;
 height:17px;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 background:#06C;
 border:none;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
margin: 0; 
}
input[type=number] {
-moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" id="value" placeholder="Amount Request (low to heigh)">
  <button id="up"></button>
  <button id="down"></button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yeah.. can i modify the arrow style?

Comment: in the image it different from the default one.

Comment: i changed my answer, if it is use full , don't forget to tick the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131543/discussion-between-rishi-and-jishnu-v-s).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove min and max attribute it will run automatically..
Please try i think you need same like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Amount request (low to high) " style="width:250px;"><br>
</div>
```